# Enable cURL on Godaddy server?

Tags: php, curl, hosting, plesk

I started a PHP project few days back. It works perfectly fine on my localhost. But after I uploaded my files on Godaddy (Plesk) server, a few scripts are not working. I used cURL for the pages and I am guessing that cURL is disabled on the server. I tried to find the php.ini file on the server, but could not locate it.

Also after following a few threads here, I created a php.ini file in the root directory of the server by copying it from my local server. It did not work. I don't know if I did something wrong here. Is there a way to enable cURL on the server, or to access the php.ini file or any procedure to create my own ini file?

Comment: You'll need to contact GoDaddy support for specifics.

Comment: Have you checked the output of `php -i` (console) or `phpinfo();` (Apache) to see if curl is enabled? What makes you think that curl is not working?

Comment: because only the scripts that need cURL are not working. Others are fine.

Comment: I contacted the support services. they said it will need some time.